# Сообщение поверх главной формы

Tags: winapi, delphi

Имеется форма fsOnTop, мне нужно вывести сообщение MessageDlg.
Если оно вызывается, например, при нажатии кнопки на форме, всё происходит как полагается. Однако в моей программе также имеется ещё один поток (TThread), и если же вывод сообщения вызывает этот поток, сообщение не находится поверх главной формы, т.е. просто прячется за ней. Подскажите пожалуйста как избавиться от этой проблемы.

Comment: Ага, происходит это когда вызываю сообщение из тела потока, если вызвать в Synchronize, то всё работает как надо... Может это связано с тем, что программа дожидается выбора пользователя и приостанавливает поток???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Подскажите пожалуйста как избавиться от этой проблемы.

`MessageDlg` в `Delphi` вызывает `API` `MessageBox` с флагом `MB_TASKMODAL`, влияние которого распространяется на **текущий поток**. С этим и связана проблема.

Решить задачу можно несколькими способами.

Либо вызывать `MessageDlg` в основном потоке (Ваш вариант с `Synchronize`).

Либо, вместо `MessageDlg` вызывать `MessageBox` без флага `MB_TASKMODAL`, а первым параметром передать ей дескриптор основного окна. Это т.н. "**owner** window", ниже которого не может опуститься `popup` - "**owned** `window`", [по-определению](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599(v=vs.85).aspx#owned_windows):

> An owned window is always above its owner in the z-order.

p.s.: по поводу второго варианта у меня есть сомнения, т.к. окна не принадлежат одному потоку, но, насколько я знаю, в MSDN замечаний по этому поводу не было.